# Include file in config.php

Tags: php, session, moodle

I have 2 projects, one Moodle, the other is the authentication project. I am using this second project to store user's DB config. This is trying to implement multi-tenancy. On the auth project, when a user logs in it fetches the database config and it is to pass it to the config.php file params. These params are stored as global sessions variables in the auth app. So I included the dashboard.php (from the auth app) file in the config.php (Moodle) thus. Once in included, and Moodle page refreshed, it returns error on the page.

```
    $userloogedin = '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/register/dashboard.php';
include( $userloogedin );
```

On the second project when I refreshed the page it returns error on the page. What could be the problem? Am I including it in a wrong way?

Comment: and of course, you looked in your `error_log` and have an error message for us?

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: No error log. Just displays ```error``` on the Moodle page.

Comment: Raise the log level (LogLevel debug), restart Apache, try again.

Comment: Thanks , @Nic3500 boss. I got it working this way: $path = ```$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path .= "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/register/dashboard.php";
include($path);``` But still contemplating if it is really included.

Comment: Does it display the error message again?  Look at what the dashboard.php file does, if you see the content is produces, you got it!  You could just add `echo "hello";` in it and see if it is executed.

Comment: Thanks all. Got it working by moving the project into the same MAMP server.